# Cannot set property 1 of undefined - javascript/google maps api

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to build an array of values that i can use to add markers to google maps, however keep getting this error. Code below, any suggestions as to where im going wrong (pretty new to this...) are much appreciated.

Thanks
Paul

```
      var result2 = sforce.connection.queryAll("select Name,Lat__c,Long__c, Status__c from Site__c where Lat__c != null");

  var records = result2.getArray('records');
  var store_locations = new Array();
  var Approved_store_locations = new Array();
  var Rejected_store_locations = new Array();
  var a=0,b=0,c=0;

  for (var j=0; j< records.length; j++) 
      {
        var record = records[j];

        if (record.Status__c == "IB Approved")
        {

            Approved_store_locations[a][1] = [[new google.maps.LatLng(record.Lat__c, record.Long__c)],[record.Name]];
            alert(Approved_store_locations[a][1]);
            a++ 
        } else if (record.Status__c == "Site Dead")
        {

            Rejected_store_locations[b][1] = [[new google.maps.LatLng(record.Lat__c, record.Long__c)],[record.Name]]; 
            b++
        } else
        {

            store_locations[c][1] = [[new google.maps.LatLng(record.Lat__c, record.Long__c)],[record.Name]]; 
            c++
        }

      }

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
  for (i=0; i < store_locations.length; i++)
  {
    marker2 = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: store_locations[i][0],
        title: store_locations[0][i],
        map: map
    });
    iconfile = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/yellow-dot.png';
    marker2.setIcon(iconfile);
  }

  for (i=0; i < Approved_store_locations.length; i++)
  {
    marker3 = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: Approved_store_locations[i][0],
        title: store_locations[0][i],
        map: map
    });
    iconfile = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/green-dot.png';
    marker3.setIcon(iconfile);
  }


  for (i=0; i < Rejected_store_locations.length; i++)
  {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker(
    {
        position: Rejected_store_locations[i][0],
        title: store_locations[0][i],
        map: map
    });
    iconfile = 'http://maps.google.com/mapfiles/ms/icons/red-dot.png';
    marker3.setIcon(iconfile);
  }
```

Comment: where in the code does this error appear? please provide more information. also I can see out of scope marker3 object in the last loop

Comment: on this line:store_locations[c][1] = [[new google.maps.LatLng(record.Lat__c, record.Long__c)],[record.Name]];

Answer (score 0):

currently you only have `store_locations=Array();` , no items inside.

Before you try to access an item, you must create it, for example:

```
  var store_locations = [[]];
  var Approved_store_locations =  [[]];
  var Rejected_store_locations =  [[]];
  var a=0,b=0,c=0;

  for (var j=0; j< records.length; j++) 
      {
        var record = records[j];

        if (record.Status__c == "IB Approved")
        {

            Approved_store_locations[a][1] = [[new google.maps.LatLng(record.Lat__c, record.Long__c)],[record.Name]];
            alert(Approved_store_locations[a][1]);
            a++;Approved_store_locations.push([]);

        } else if (record.Status__c == "Site Dead")
        {

            Rejected_store_locations[b][1] = [[new google.maps.LatLng(record.Lat__c, record.Long__c)],[record.Name]]; 
            b++;Rejected_store_locations.push([])
        } else
        {

            store_locations[c][1] = [[new google.maps.LatLng(record.Lat__c, record.Long__c)],[record.Name]]; 
            c++;store_locations.push([]);
        }

      }
```